# SQL Server Report Services Not Configuring

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2008

This is kind of Frustrating as I know I am doing everything right, however SQL Server Reporting Services are not configured:

**To Configure I did these following steps**

1. Opened Reporting Services Configuration Manager
2. Click Connect
3. Clicked Web Services URL

   - Here (first) I just used the default values (just giving a different Name)
   - Then I tried to configure by using the Host Header
   - Clicked Advance Gave Host Header a Name from DNS something like (rs.constoso.com)
   - Removed "All assigned listener"
4. I change the Database

   - Created a new report database
   - Connected to database server
   - Used both Sharepoint Mode (cause eventually that is what I am trying to do) and the native mode.
5. However no matter what I do the reporting service seems to not respond. When I click the Web Service URL it says the Reporting Service has some Error.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong (is there something I am forgetting somewhere?)

The Error I get is as follow:

> Reporting Services Error 
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
>  
>   The report server has encountered a configuration error.
>   (rsServerConfigurationError) Get Online Help
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  SQL Server Reporting Services

My System:

1. Windows Server 2008 R2
2. SQL server 2008
3. Has Sharepoint 2010 installed

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. I was using wrong user from AD.